# Drools: How to use forall in decision table to match anyof or all the items in the comma seperated string

Tags: drools

How to define Drool's conditional element `forall` in decision table? for ex. "fruit" and "vegetable" true if the input matches one of the comma separated string. "abc combo" true if the input string contains all of the comma separated string.  I have achieved the same using a custom function, just want to know if the same can be achieved by `forall`?[image]

Comment: I can't tell if you want a for-all or any, your title and question are conflicting and unclear.

Comment: Thanks. I need both. For row one and two it has to match any, for row 3 it has to match with all. As of now i am doing with java function. matchAll(item, $param) and matchAny(item, $param)

Answer (score 0):

To match either use the || in the forAll and to match all use &&

### Example

- eval(forall(&&){name == "$"})
- eval(forall(||){name == "$"})